# Changing Wordpress http to https behind a Load Balancer with ProxyPass

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I run a Wordpress behind a other (main) webserver. The main Server does have a rule to redirect all requests to /wpa to the Wordpress Server with a ProxyPass

```
ProxyPass /wpa/ http://vm.example.com/wpa/
ProxyPassReverse /wpa/ http://vm.example.com/wpa/
```

Wordpress itself comes with this .htaccess file at the Wordpress root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wpa/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wpa/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Everything is working fine with http. But I want to switch to https and this is a problem.
The SSL termination is done at a Load Balancer.

The thing is, that all traffic behind the Load Balancer is non-ssl.
If I change the Wordpress homeurl and siteurl from http to https, I get a redirect error (loop).

I tried to use a rule like this at the main server:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/wpa/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/wpa/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Still get a redirect error. I tried to check RewriteLog but I failed finding the right information.

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the below code in `wp-config.php`,

   ```
   define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
   define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
   if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
   ```
2. Check your `.htaccess` file; it should be clean.
3. Re-save the permalink.
4. If using a CDN, enable 443 port.

Comment: Thank you, the $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on' works for me. We also use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] to use the Hostname/URL from the main apache server.

Comment: Some more: I use my old htaccess. I did not clean it before, but it works fine.